# Generate fake data for Enum in Bogus library

Tags: c#, bogus

I want to create fake data with `Bogus` library to test database performance. Here my book example:

```
    public class Book
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Genre
    {
        Poetry,
        Romance,
        Thriller,
        Travel
    }
}
```

Also, I have rules for each property in `Book` class to generate fake data.

```
        public static Faker<Book> Book = new Faker<Book>()
            .StrictMode(true)
            .RuleFor(x => x.Id, f => f.Random.Guid())
            .RuleFor(x => x.Title, f => f.Company.CompanyName())
            .RuleFor(x => x.Price, f => f.Random.Double())
            .RuleFor(x => x.ISBN, f => $"ISBN_{f.Random.Guid()}")
            .RuleFor(x => x.Genre, f => ???);
```

My question is - How can I generate random value for enum `Genre`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is available in [the documentation](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#the-great-c-example) itself,

Try with

```
.RuleFor(x => x.Genre, f =>f.PickRandom<Genre>());
```

Your code will look like,

```
public static Faker<Book> Book = new Faker<Book>()
        .StrictMode(true)
        .RuleFor(x => x.Id, f => f.Random.Guid())
        .RuleFor(x => x.Title, f => f.Company.CompanyName())
        .RuleFor(x => x.Price, f => f.Random.Double())
        .RuleFor(x => x.ISBN, f => $"ISBN_{f.Random.Guid()}")
        .RuleFor(x => x.Genre, f => f.PickRandom<Genre>());
```

[POC: .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vtNTmM)